# Seeking algorithms for fast, simple linear regressions

Tags: regression, algorithms, numerics

I am working on a project which requires me to work in a proprietary programming language. Unfortunately, this language lacks a matrix algebra library. In this environment, I would like to perform a few simple regressions with slightly overdetermined systems: for example, fitting a least-squares linear equation to no more than 4 XY coordinate pairs; or, fitting a least-squares parabola (which can be expressed as a linear regression by adding the X² term) to no more than 5 XY coordinate pairs. The system needs to respond in real time, so speed is important.

I know that [sorting networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) are a useful tool for ordering small data sets, sometimes outperforming more general sorting algorithms. I am wondering whether there are similar optimized algorithms for small regression problems such as the ones I have described.

Comment: Considerable gains can be made when, say, the $x$ coordinates don't change from one problem to the next.  (I give a worked example at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/65841/664.)  Thus, you can get the best answers by being as specific and narrow as possible in your characterization of the problems you need to solve, including how many coordinate pairs you will have and exactly what forms the models will take.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, I should have mentioned that I can count on the X values to be uniformly spaced.  I will have a look at your example.

Comment: In that case, my example points the way :-).  The idea is to precompute most of what you need, reducing the actual regressions to computing a linear combination of the $y$ data.